# Pandas xlsxwriter format a column after writing

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe, export-to-excel

I am trying to format a column and row after writing them into excel from a pandas df. I can't seem to get it working. in the below code only the lines pertaning to the xlwriter are the ones that I'm trying to confirm.`sh.set_column` and `sh.set_row` are the ones that is not working as intended. No error but it just doesn't apply the format to the excel file, neither does it apply to `sh.autofit`.

```
FOLDER = r"C:\Users\Data\Project"
FILE_NAME = r"\Q2 Products Growth Rates by Groups.xlsx"
PATH = FOLDER + FILE_NAME
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(PATH, engine="xlsxwriter")
wb = writer.book
# Adding header format
title_format = wb.add_format({"num_format": '_($* #,##0_);_($* (#,##0);_($* "-"??_);_(@_)', "bold": True, "font_color": "blue"})  # type: ignore # pylint: disable=line-too-long
# Adding currency format
fmt_currency = wb.add_format({"num_format": '_($* #,##0_);_($* (#,##0);_($* "-"??_);_(@_)', "bold": False})  # type: ignore # pylint: disable=line-too-long
# Adding percentage format
fmt_percent = wb.add_format({"num_format": "0.0%", "bold": False})  # type: ignore # pylint: disable=line-too-long
# Adding date format
fmt_date = wb.add_format({"num_format": "mmm-yy", "bold": True})  # type: ignore # pylint: disable=line-too-long

for cat in ["A", "B"]:
    df_category = df_raw[
        (df_raw["MEGA_CATEGORY"] == cat)
    ]

    for lvl in ["MTH", "QTR"]:
        if (lvl == "QTR") & (cat == "B"):
            x = df_category.PERIOD_445_QTR
            FILE = "Prod A Quarterly"
        elif (lvl == "QTR") & (cat == "A"):
            x = df_category.PERIOD_445_QTR
            FILE = "B Quarterly"
        elif (lvl == "MTH") & (cat == "B"):
            x = df_category.PERIOD_445
            FILE = "A Monthly"
        else:
            x = df_category.PERIOD_445
            FILE = "B Monthly"

        ### some more code ###

        df_final = (
            pd.concat([df_crosstab, future])
            .rename(index={"Wave 1": "Current"})
        )
        df_final.to_csv(r"C:\Users\Data.csv")

        ### some more code ###

        df_growth = pd.concat([df_growth_2022, df_growth_2023], axis=1)  # type: ignore
        df_final.transpose().to_excel(writer, sheet_name= FILE + " Data" )
        sh = writer.sheets[FILE + " Data"]
        sh.set_column(1,1,None ,fmt_date)
        sh.autofit()

        df_growth.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=FILE +" Growth Rates")
        sh = writer.sheets[FILE +" Growth Rates"]
        sh.set_row(0,None, fmt_date)

        sh.autofit()
writer.close()
```

In the above code everything works well but I cannot seem to get the column and row formatted after they are written on the sheet using the set_column and set_row properties. Is that not the right functions to use for that? Is there a better way to format a whole column or row after writing a whole data frame to an excel sheet.

I would appreciate any help anyone can provide in what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

formatting and other xlsxwriter adjustments to have effect, they usually have to be written using ExcelWriter.

Try as below,

adjust the end of your code after the row `df_growth = pd.concat([df_growth_2022, df_growth_2023], axis=1)  # type: ignore'` to look as the following:

```
with pd.ExcelWriter(PATH, engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:
    df_final.transpose().to_excel(writer, sheet_name=FILE + " Data")
    df_growth.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=FILE +" Growth Rates")

    wb = writer. Book
    sh = writer. Sheets[FILE + " Data"]
    sh.set_column(1,1,None ,fmt_date)
    sh.autofit()

    sh2 = writer. Sheets[FILE +" Growth Rates"]
    sh2.set_row(0,None, fmt_date)
    sh2.autofit()
```

note: you will not need 'writer. Close()'